# Emphatic form of nota bene

Tags: translation

I suppose this is really about Latin, but since there is no Latin SE an answer using modern Italian would be welcome.

In the days of my youth we had a Latin teacher who used the phrase *nota benissime* when he wanted us to take extra special notice. I may have misremembered the phrase, and in any case it may not be proper Latin. I would be interested to know what if any the proper Italian would be (bonus points if you can provide the Latin as well).

Specifically, if *nota bene* means *note well* what would be the phrases for *note very well* and *note as well as you possibly could*? I would only ever be using these phrases to English speakers (physics students!) in a tongue in cheek context so there is no need to strive for great precision.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @JohnRennie!

Comment: [Area 51 Latin Language Stack Exchange Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Latin phrase, but it more or less works in Italian too. In Italian, “note very well” would be *nota benissimo*, while “note as well as you possibly could” could be phrased *nota meglio possibile*.

The Latin superlative of *bene*, however, was *optime*; so, *nota optime*, if anything.